# Canon EDSDK sample code - help to understand save file to location

Tags: file-transfer, canon-sdk

I am new to the EDSDK, but so far have been very happy with the results.  I have my program working just fine saving to the camera, however when I set to saveTo Host I'm unclear on where it thinks it's supposed to save to.

Everything appears to work.  Callback function gets called, progress bar animates but I have no idea where it thinks it's pointing the file to.

the closest I get is finding where the @"download" command is issued, the argument to this call should be getting cast as a (EdsDirectoryItemRef)

This all seems to be coming from the EDSCALLBACK handleObjectEvent but I can't figure out how it gets constructed.

Ideally I'd like to be able to specify where on disk I want the images to go.  Can someone provide some aid?

[edit]

Okay, I see the images are going into the build directory, but perhaps someone could help me to understand why.  Or even better how to specify a path for myself.

Answer (score 1):

When you set saveTo_Host, the image is stored on a temporary memory in the camera. The camera then triggers a DirItemRequestTransfer event that would call the callback function 'handleObjectEvent'. The reference to the image, stored in the temporary camera memory, is passed to the callback function.
Within the handleObjectEvent callback function you probably would be creating a file stream and using EdsDownload to download the file to the location on the PC (which is specified by the file stream).

When you create a file stream you need to specify a file name (the first argument). This file name determines where the image would be stored. If you just specify the file name without a path the image gets stored in the build directory. If you would like to save the file in a particular location you need to specify the file name along with its path.

Hope this helps.